# Azure datafactory "Set_Variabe" array and "FOR_EACH" exe_pipelines activities

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

as you can see in the following images, the matrix reaches the activity (Exe_pipeline) completely, but it does not allow separating the values ​​for the different parameters. try a (Split), but it doesn't work.

*img1 activity (for_each) receives array string correctly *Img_2 evidences that it sends the array correctly, but indicating the value to each parameter does not work. example: @item().FileJson *img_3 if I send only @item () if it presents the whole array.

Can someone tell me how to separate the information that comes in item (). other than @item. ???

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you get any error message? The variable array format should be [1,2,3], not a json string.

Comment: Hello Leon Yue , thanks for answering if you allow Json only that I have not achieved what I just updated, Happy day.

Comment: I think the error is happened in Foreach item, can you show us the expression?